# Сброс пароля bios на ноутбуке Toshiba Satellite L775-a1w?

Tags: ноутбук

Подскажите, как можно сбросить пароль, установленный в BIOS. Пароль не для входа в настройки BIOS, а появляющийся сразу же при включении ноутбука.

Comment: Добавьте фотографию экрана с паролем "при включении ноутбука".

Comment: Объясните, что значит *пароль не вход в bios а при включении ноутбука появляется сразу*. Напишите, какие действия и для чего предпринимали.

Comment: пароль не на вход в bios и не на вход после загрузки системы, а как только включаешь ноут, показывается логотип Toshiba и требует пароль. После трех неудачных попыток, выключается

Comment: У скупщиков краденного купил?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме ресурса.

Answer (score 1):

При сбросе настроек BIOS'а к значениям по умолчанию очистятся и пароли.
На ноутбуках Toshiba такой сброс осуществляется замыкаем контактных площадок на материнской плате под модулями памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Toshiba satellite pro U400
Для сброса биос:

1. Снимаем аккумулятор, крышку памяти, планку памяти, отключаем БП.
2. Находим треугольные оловянную напайки ввиде контактов:  < >
3. замыкаем их отверткой и держим, вставляем планку памяти в нижний (первый) слот не до конца (отвертка мешает), но прижимаем максимально вниз, чтобы был контакт и нажимаем кнопку включения.  Ждем запуска.
4. отпускаем кнопку,  отпускаем контакты, выключаем бук.
5. ставим все на место в обратном порядке.
6. BIOS без пароля в DEFAULT настройках

По инструкциям на Youtube и в остальных пабликах, везде рекомендовали переставлять RAM во второй слот, чтобы был доступ к контактам - не получилось, ноут не стартовал.